# How to create customized admin dashboard by using the wordpress database?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a website using wordpress and it's working fine. My question is how can I create a customized admin section outside the wordpress environment which manipulates the website database?

I have tried it by editing the post data directly from the wordpress database, but its not being reflected on the page. While update page using the wordpress dashboard changes are reflected to the page. I am not getting why the changes are not reflect to page when edit the post data directly from the database.

Thanks in advance help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "manipulate the website database" What exactly are you wanting to do? You can change/add to the wordpress dashboard and create your own admin. It's kind of complicated and you need a child theme. If you don't have a child theme yet get one-it's most helpful for customizing Wordpress.